# When to use the Y-Namespace

Tags: namespaces, naming-conventions, abap

Is there a generally accepted convention among ABAP developers when to use the Y-Namespace and when to use the Z-Namespace for customer repository objects?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The original intention was to use the namespace `Y...` for centrally developed solutions (head office) and `Z...` for local development (branch office) - you can still find this in older (and perhaps even more recent) [documentation](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_46c/helpdata/en/2a/6b0b1f547a11d189600000e829fbbd/frameset.htm). In my experience however, unless someone enforces these rules for a certain system landscape, each developer just chooses whatever seems appropriate at the time...

Comment: That's interesting, thanks! I never knew about the distinction between head office and branches.

Answer (score 1):

Every system I've worked on used the Y... namespace for objects create in dev which were not  intended to be transported into test/QA/prod/whatever. The Z... namespace is used for custom development as per normal.

But it could just be an Australian thing...

Answer (score -1):

I can remember myself reading an article where the author mentioned the uses of Y and Z conventions depending on the type of development you were trying to do, and it went as follows:

Z names: Used when the custom development was done from scratch by the developers.

Y names: Used when the custom development is mostly a copy of a standard program.

I personally never used Y before and so it's been to date, but I found that interesting to know anyway.